# How would I go about querying MongoDB efficiently using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, filtering

I'm trying to query MongoDB with text.

Say I enter "Oven", the server should find all contraptions and users, including the word "Oven" in a field called "title" for contraptions and a field called "username" for users.

Right now, my code looks like this:

```js
const foundContraptions = await Contraptions.find({});
const foundUsers = await Profiles.find({});

const filteredContraptions = QueryContraptions(foundContraptions, query);
const filteredUsers = QueryUsers(foundUsers, query);

function QueryContraptions(arr, query) {
    const filtered = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const contraption = arr[i];
        if (contraption.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
            filtered.push(removeFile(contraption));
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}

function QueryUsers(arr, query) {
    const filtered = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const user = arr[i];
        if (user.username.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
            filtered.push(removeToken(user));
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

This works perfectly fine, but assuming I have a **lot** of data in my DB, at some point I would get an Error HeapOutOfMemory, or it would take a long time to execute the loops.
So I wanted to ask how I would go about querying MongoDB efficiently using Mongoose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an answer by myself using the MongoDB query operators

```js
const contraption = await Contraptions.find({ 'title': { '$eq': query } }).catch(err => { console.log(err); });
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/